# Keras Lambda layer: How to multiply input with a group constant matrices?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, keras-layer

I have an input size of `(k, n, n)`, which represents `k` `n`-by-`n` matrices. I have another group of constant matrices `(k, n, n)`. I intend to multiply the corresponding matrices of these two groups of `k` matrices, which will lead to a `(k, n, n)` output. When using `Lambda` in keras to implement this, I faced the issue of batch size -- I need to repeat the constant matrices along the batch size dimension for `batch_size` times, and then I can use `batch_dot`. However, `batch_size` is given as a tensor, which cannot be accepted by `repeat_elements`. What should I do to implement this layer?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use `tile`. Let `y` be the constant matrix tensor. Then,

```py
from keras import backend as K

def my_lambda_function(x):
    K.batch(x, K.tile(K.expand_dims(y, axis=0), (K.shape(x)[0], 1, 1, 1)), axes=(3, 2))
```